# MySQL TRUNCATE accuracy is off by one

Tags: mysql

The MySQL server I'm using is 5.5.41. I also want to note I did not design this database.

The problem I'm running in to, is when using MySQL's TRUCATE function, I seem to be getting an off by one error. As in it's not accurate. See the attached screen shot for what I mean.

[image]

If the option of changing the table structure was limited, is there a way around fixing this bug and returning the correct number?

Comment: Do try and use images to represent plain-text data, instead paste that in as plain-text. Images are difficult to work with, can't be copy-pasted into answers, and are hostile to people with screen readers.

Comment: @tadman you mean *Don't

Comment: Right, don't. That one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not exact. The actual value of `70.85` is probably something like `70.84999999`, but it's being shown rounded off to the nearest 2 decimal places. `TRUNCATE` takes the actual value and just discards all the decimal places beyond what you requested, so it always rounds down, not to the nearest value, so it becomes `70.84`.

If you don't want to lose accuracy like this, use the `DECIMAL` datatype instead of `FLOAT`. You could also use `ROUND(reserve_amount, 2)` instead of `TRUNCATE(reserve_amount, 2)`.